# Custom font in TileService UI

Tags: android, wear-os, wear-tile

In [TileService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/tiles/TileService) for font style we have to use [LayoutElementBuilders.FontStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/tiles/LayoutElementBuilders.FontStyle.Builder) to change font style. But in
[`LayoutElementBuilders.FontStyle.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/tiles/LayoutElementBuilders.FontStyle.Builder) and [`LayoutElementBuilders.Text`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/tiles/LayoutElementBuilders.Text) class I can't see any method for custom font.

Is `TileService` new UI Builder api support custom font?

How can i set custom font in TileService UI ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a supported feature. Tiles are rendered in a different process, so don't automatically have the same fonts.

See https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/issues/153

> Setting custom fonts in tiles is not allowed as tiles are rendering in a system context and so there are security concerns with loading fonts into a privileged process.